# NetworkImageView - Displaying more than one image from php file

Tags: android, json, android-listview, imageview

I'm working in AndroidStudio using `NetworkImageView`, I have to display the images in the PHP file below (There are more than 2 of them but it would be too long to list here), in a `ListView`. I understand I should use `GetImageUrl`? In all the examples I found, they used an image url, but in this case what would I put there?

Or do I have to include `image_url` somewhere in the `ImageLoader`?

```
{
    "image_url": "http://tashdarcy.com/menu/images/1.jpg",
    "record_id": 11868,
    "title": "Congratulations to John on EPSRC funding",
    "date": "08/12/2014",
    "short_info": "A new EPSRC grant has been awarded to Dr John Batchelor as part of a GBP 1.9M project entitled: Adaptive Assistive Rehabilitative Technology"
}
```

I have this in the xml file for the list items:

```
 <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageUrl"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
```

I have an `imageLoader` in another class

```
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    instance = this;

    reqQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(reqQueue, new ImageLoader.ImageCache()
    {
        private final LruCache<String, Bitmap> mCache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(20);

        public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
            mCache.put(url, bitmap);
        }
        public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
            return mCache.get(url);
```

Can you tell me how to implement it? I understand it needs to go in the `getView` of my list class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too sure what your problem is....everything is explained in the link you posted.

1. You need to parse that JSON into POJO object
2. Then, use that list of POJO objects to populate an ArrayAdapter that ultimately populates the ListView

In the `ArrayAdapter` you will set the individual `NetworkImageView` url using the `setImageUrl` method...for example, this is a code snippet of the `getView` method of the `ArrayAdapter` from the link you posted...

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.lv_picasa_row, null);
    }

    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag(R.id.id_holder);       

    if (holder == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder(v);
        v.setTag(R.id.id_holder, holder);
    }        

    PicasaEntry entry = getItem(position);
    if (entry.getThumbnailUrl() != null) {
        holder.image.setImageUrl(entry.getThumbnailUrl(), mImageLoader);
    } else {
        holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_image);
    }

    holder.title.setText(entry.getTitle());

    return v;
}
```

to be more especific, here's the `ArrayAdapter` implementation...

https://github.com/ogrebgr/android_volley_examples/blob/master/src/com/github/volley_examples/misc/PicasaArrayAdapter.java

as you can see, you have full access to source code examples. This is how you set the image url...

```
holder.image.setImageUrl(entry.getThumbnailUrl(), mImageLoader);
```

where `image` is your `NetworkImageView`. What isn't still clear?

Comment: Sorry, thank you for the help. I edited my post if it is any help to you, do you think you could explain a little further because I think the implementation in this example is different to the way I've tried to do it?

Comment: @user3360721 Sorry, but I have already answered your question and you know it's not possible to write a whole solution in this Q&A format. Your supposed to ask questions about a specific problem